# Query to find groups of strings where character case differ

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL Server table with a column where records are:

1. strings with different character case variants (in the below example
   'Toyota' and 'Honda' in various variants) or
2. strings with one variant only (in the below example 'BMW')

```html
Id  Make
1   HONDA
2   Honda
3   TOYOTA
4   Toyota
5   toyota
6   BMW
7   BMW
```

I need to write a query to show only the strings which have varying character case variants. The database is set to case insensitive.

The result would look something like

```html
honda
toyota
```

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? If you have data that is case sensitive, however, why aren't you using a case sensitive collation (either for the database, or the column)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS()` as

```
SELECT Make
FROM T T1
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM T
              WHERE Make = UPPER(T1.Make)
                    AND
                    Make != T1.Make collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
);
```

Or even

```
SELECT LOWER(Make) Make
FROM T T1
WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT 1
              FROM T
              WHERE Make = UPPER(T1.Make)
                    AND
                    Make != T1.Make collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
)
GROUP BY LOWER(Make);
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a3a575ff5720ff16ccc06e2cc9bc9690)**

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a case-sensitive collation to make the comparison.  Here is a simple method:

```
select lower(str)
from (values ('honda'), ('Honda'), ('x'), ('x')) v(str)
group by lower(str)
having min(str collate Latin1_General_CS_AS) <> max(str collate Latin1_General_CS_AS);
```